# How to show independence and interpret the result

Tags: distributions, self-study, independence

> If $X$ is symmetrically distributed  about zero , then show that $U=|X|$ and 
>   $$V = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{}
>            +1, & X \geq0 \\
>            -1, & X<0
>         \end{array}
>    \right .$$
>   are independently distributed and interpret the result.

Here distribution is not given only it is known that it symmetrically distributed . I think this result holds for continuous and discrete distribution . How can I show independence and interpret the result . Please help

**Edit:** Here independence means statistical independence.

> **Defn1:** Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if
>    $$ F_{XY}(x,y)=F_X(x).F_Y(y) \forall x,y \in R$$
>     where $ F_{XY}(x,y)$ is their joint distribution function and $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$ are their marginal distribution functions.

I also know the independence with PDF/PMF.

> **Defn2:** Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ , forming an absolutely continuous random vector,are independent if and only if
>   $$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x).f_Y(y) \forall x,y \in R$$
>    where $ f_{XY}(x,y)$ is their joint probability density function and $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ are their marginal probability density functions.

For discrete case $f$ is replaced by $p$ .

Comment: What definitions of independence do you know?

Comment: @whuber : I give the definitions in my question. Please see it.

Comment: It's not going to lead you instantly to the answer, but did you notice that $X = UV$?

Comment: OK, have you tried to apply each definition to your problem? To do so, you will need to obtain the CDF or PDF of both $U$ and $V$. Obviously they must be related to the CDF and PDF of $X$. Precisely how?  (If you work this through carefully you will be able to find a class of random variables $X$ for which the conclusion of the problem is false!  Take a close look at the *asymmetry* in the definition of $V$.)

Comment: @Glen_b: Yes. The result is quite obvious . But I am unable to show the independence. By the way like your comment.

Comment: If if the pdf of $X$ is $f_X$, what is the pdf of $U$?

Comment: @Glen_b:I think $f_U(u)=2f_X(u),u \geq 0$

Comment: If the pdf of $X$ is $f_X$, can you write down what $f_V$ is?

Answer (score 3):

The result "sign and magnitude are independently distributed" is certainly true for *continuous* distributions symmetric about zero. Notably, it can be applied in the derivation of the test statistic in Wilcoxon's signed-rank test for symmetry.

Assume $X$ is continuous with distribution function $F$.

Then for every $t$,

\begin{align}
P(|X|<t\mid \text{sgn}(X)=1)&=\small\frac{P(-t<X<t\,,\,X> 0)}{P(\text{sgn}(X)=1)}
\\&=\small\frac{P(0<X<t)}{P(X> 0)}
\\&=\small\frac{F(t)-F(0)}{1-F(0)}
\\&=2F(t)-1 & \small[\,\because F(0)=1/2\,]
\\&=F(t)-(1-F(t)) 
\\&=F(t)-F(-t) & \small[\,\because F(t)+F(-t)=1\,]
\\&=P(|X|<t)
\end{align}

Similarly, it holds that $P(|X|<t\mid \text{sgn}(X)=-1)=P(|X|<t)$

Thus the distribution of $|X|$ is independent of $\text{sgn}(X)$.